# SharePoint list Display Manager name for a user

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I'm looking to display the managers name (defined in AD for the user) in a column depending on a selection from another column.  For example.

Column 1 - Employee Name
Column 2 - Department
Column 3 - Manager

Column 1 is populated with the employee name and saved.  It's a "User or Group" type column
Column 2 is "Person or Group" column with the "Show Field" option set as department.  I have a workflow that starts on a new entry that takes the column 1 data and applies it to Column 2 thus display the users department.

My issue is in the "Show Fields" option there is no manager selection.  Is there a way to display this as a selection or is there another way for me to populate a users manager depending on the employee selection?

The other option I've tried is doing a 2010 workflow for "Find Manager of" current employee (output to variable:manager) and then to update the manager column to use the data from Variable manager but nothing seems to display. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQgad.jpg)  Perhaps I've done something wrong here though..

Any help would be appreciated.

Updated screenshot information
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQgad.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of Manager column? Make it 'Person or Group'.
In the workflow, select return field as 'Login Name' and try. Below is the screen shot.[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work but maybe I'm doing this wrong.  Here is a screenshot of my workflow.  See below

Comment: Ok. First thing, do not create your own workflow local variable. Keep the same variable created default by workflow. Second, do not use 'Update Item' instead use 'Set Item'. What is the data type you have used for 'Managers Name' column? it must be 'Person or Group'. Lastly have you tried the below script JQuery I have provided? there you can get all three values on New Form, no need of workflow.

Comment: Hi Sniper.. Thanks for the feedback.  I have not tried the jquery script as I'm not all familiar with it..  Perhaps I'll have to figure out how it works though.  My manager field is a "person or Group".  I configured it as set item however I have similar results as before.  The work flow completes but nothing is visible in the "Manager Name" column.

Comment: What do you mean "Don't create a local variable"?  I didn't select it anythign manual.. Selecting the employee as the lookup it auto created the variable for me..  Is this not correct?

Comment: Hi Barnie.. Seems like you are testing it with System Account login. Try to login with different user which has contribute rights. test it and let me know. Also, use the 'log to the workflow history list' action and log the local variable 'manager' before assigning it to 'Manage Name' column and check what value is coming. Send me screen shot of it.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to even come back here and update but I figured out my problem....  If you look in my screenshot you will notice there is a "run items in parrallel".. I didn't even know this was an option and must have added it by accident.  Sniper thank you so much for all your efforts.  I really appreciate it.  In the end my original workflow worked.

Comment: Its ok Barnie. These things happen with developers. I am happy that your issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the three values on the New Form itself and then just save it.
Use SPServices jQuery. Just download the latest one.  Below is the script.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/your path to JS/SiteAssets/JS/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>  
<script type="text/jscript" src="/your path to JS/SiteAssets/JS/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

        var managerName;
       

 var userName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser();
 

        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
            async: false,
            AccountName: userName,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) 
  {

                managerName = $(xData.responseXML).text();
                var managerLength = managerName.length;
                var indexofManager = managerName.indexOf("ManagerPublic");
                managerName = managerName.substring(indexofManager+13, managerLength);  
                var indexOffalse = managerName.indexOf("false");  
                managerName = managerName.substring(0, indexOffalse);
  
             }
        }); 


 var UserDept = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({  
 fieldName: "Department",   
 debug: false  
 });

 var CurrentUser = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
 fieldName: "Title", 
 debug: false
 });

 $("input[title*='Employee Name']").val(CurrentUser); // For assigning to SharePoint column named 'Employee Name'  

 $("input[title*='Department']").val(UserDept); // For assigning to SharePoint column named 'Department'  

 var Mgr =  $().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker({
 peoplePickerDisplayName: "Manager", // For assigning to SharePoint column named 'Manager'
 valueToSet: managerName,
   checkNames: true
 }); 

});
</script>
```